# How to create a local database with the snapshot available on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clone, sql-server-express, snapshot

I terminated the `instance`, which is running on `AWS` long back. now i have a `snapshot` of that Application on `AWS`. I want to create a `local database` with the `exact data` that is present in the `snapshot` available on `AWS`. How can i do that ? the database is `SQL Server Express` And the Application is a dot net Application.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an EC2 snapshot?

If that's the case, you need to recreate the instance, backup your database properly, copy the backup to your local machine and restore it in your local database.

Comment: Yes, EC2 snapshot.

Comment: @John in this case you'll need to recreate the machine to access you data, unfortunately. Please consider accepting this as the answer to your question. Good luck!